# Sentence starting with て?

Tags: words, expressions, particle-って

I was listening to this podcast on Himalaya (Link given below) and I came across this sentence which starts with て, I'm not sure why it starts with て, can anyone please explain this? Also I'm not sure what does ていうのと、あとは means here? Is it some sort of a fixed expression which means "other than that" or something, how do you break this expression down?

​‎ていうのと、あとはやっぱ怒らせないようにっていうのを考えてすごく対応してくれてるって言うのがわかって…

Source: At around **07:22** at http://www.himalaya.com/jp/episode/125679/53455746?Share_from=App&Influencer_uid=1037891&Share_to=Others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This て is the same as って, the colloquial quotative particle similar to と. The small-tsu is unheard because it's located at the beginning of the sentence. (When written, this っ is usually omitted at the beginning of a sentence, but may be preserved in casual light novels and such.) It may be obvious to you, but this (っ)て refers to what was said in the previous sentence.

> っていうのと、…
>   = ていうのと、…
>   = というのと、…
>   = In addition to that, ...

This あとは is like それに, a word used before the last item of a list:

> りんご、バナナ、あとはすいか！
>   An apple, a banana, *and (lastly)*, a watermelon!

But in this case, it's used almost like a filler, and its function is not very different from ていうのと ("...and...", "...to add to that...").