# What does って at the start of a sentence mean?

Tags: particle-って

胸が小さい女子って、そのコトを気にしてる場合が多いらしいぜ。

って、３組の木村さんが…！！

From  https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/01/rashii-meaning.html?m=1

The site says it means (is what Kimura from the class 3 [said]!!)

I feel it's not really correct in this case, but I want to confirm first.

Is it actually something more like ってことは in this case?

Does it translate to something like, 
So that means kimura from 3rd class is...!! (flat chested or something)

I tried finding info in various j-j dictionaries, but I failed to find any concrete examples of って being used like this.

Thank you!

Comment: This seems relevant: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66335/sentence-starting-with-%e3%81%a6

Comment: You might also see "ってか", short for というか https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the picture (he is recalling something), I think the description in the linked article is correct. This って (at the beginning of the second sentence) is a quotative particle, and it's referring to what was said in the previous balloon.

> って、３組の木村が（言ってた）…！！
>   ...which is what Kimura in the class 3 said!
>   ...that's what I heard from Kimura!

FYI, Kimura [is a male student](https://karakai-jouzu-no-takagi-san.fandom.com/wiki/Kimura) :D